# Understand how the session id is created

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to automate a website but stuck at login part. The site creates  a  session id which is sent to the webserver. I am  not able to understand this and would like someone help me on this.

Can we decompress this Javascript file?
How is the session id generated?

**Link to js file**
https://loli.lloydsbank.com/7772468/dU4t.js

**Sample Session id**
LSESSIONID=jLd1oq8U4IAmeCaBJxkp3jcLovuSpn3cUEuxEXavFtPX08UvMcR34cCha3KKy40MRkmZGK4ggBAVK1iVeq0Y

Answer (score 0):

Session IDs are usually not generated by javascript, but the by server which serves your application. Without more details we cant help you more. Each server type generates sessions in its own way, so there is no one common answer.

Generally the flow is that the server keeps a number of data with session, and either stores that data in database or directly in the cookie. Either way, either whole session data or data id is being send back as the cookie to the browser, along with html and javascript files. Look for Set-Cookie header in server response.

Comment: I know session are generated by server  and not javascript. What is LSESSIONID in the javascript file  and how is that string generated "LSESSIONID=jLd1oq8U4IAmeCaBJxkp3jcLovuSpn3cUEuxEXavFtPX08UvMcR34cCha3KKy40MRkmZGK4ggBAVK1iVeq0Y" . Any idea?